# Memory Game revealing tiles behind div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to add a new function which help me reveal all the alphabets behind the divs when I click the surrender button, I appreciate if any body can help me with this, Thanks a lot :)

[image: Screenshot of the game]

```js
var memory_array = ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'E', 'E', 'F', 'F', 'G', 'G', 'H', 'H', 'I', 'I', 'J', 'J', 'K', 'K', 'L', 'L'];
var memory_values = [];
var memory_tile_ids = [];
var tiles_flipped = 0;

Array.prototype.memory_tile_shuffle = function() {
  var i = this.length,
    j, temp;
  while (--i > 0) {
    j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    temp = this[j];
    this[j] = this[i];
    this[i] = temp;
  }
}

newBoard();

function newBoard() {
  tiles_flipped = 0;
  var output = '';
  memory_array.memory_tile_shuffle();
  for (var i = 0; i < memory_array.length; i++) {
    output += '<div id="tile_' + i + '" onclick="memoryFlipTile(this,\'' + memory_array[i] + '\')"></div>';
  }
  document.getElementById('memory_board').innerHTML = output;
}

function memoryFlipTile(tile, val) {
  if (tile.innerHTML == "" && memory_values.length < 2) {
    tile.style.background = '#FFF';
    tile.innerHTML = val;
    if (memory_values.length == 0) {
      memory_values.push(val);
      memory_tile_ids.push(tile.id);
    } else if (memory_values.length == 1) {
      memory_values.push(val);
      memory_tile_ids.push(tile.id);
      if (memory_values[0] == memory_values[1]) {
        tiles_flipped += 2;
        // Clear both arrays
        memory_values = [];
        memory_tile_ids = [];
        // Check to see if the whole board is cleared
        if (tiles_flipped == memory_array.length) {
          alert("Board cleared... generating new board");
          document.getElementById('memory_board').innerHTML = "";
          newBoard();
        }
      } else {
        function flip2Back() {
          // Flip the 2 tiles back over
          var tile_1 = document.getElementById(memory_tile_ids[0]);
          var tile_2 = document.getElementById(memory_tile_ids[1]);
          tile_1.style.background = 'url(/game/images/catA.png) no-repeat';
          tile_1.innerHTML = "";
          tile_2.style.background = 'url(/game/images/cat.png) no-repeat';
          tile_2.innerHTML = "";
          // Clear both arrays
          memory_values = [];
          memory_tile_ids = [];
        }
        setTimeout(flip2Back, 700);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
div#memory_board {
  background: #CCC;
  border: #999 1px solid;
  width: 800px;
  height: 540px;
  padding: 24px;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

div#memory_board>div {
  background: url(/game/images/cat.png) no-repeat;
  border: #000 1px solid;
  width: 71px;
  height: 71px;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 64px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="memory_board"></div>
<input type="button" name="surrender" onclick="surrender();" value="Surrender!!">
<input type="button" name="restart" onclick="newBoard();" value="Restart!!">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have a `flip2Back()` function, why not make a `flip2Front()` function as well?

You can reuse this in your `memoryFlipTile()` function below.

Basically, you just get the tiles by querying the DOM, then iteratively loop over the tile elements and reveal them.

Also, you could alternatively set the value of the tile as a data attribute.

```
<div class="tile_1" data-value="A"></div>
```

This way, the tile knows its own value instead of trying to manage parallel arrays with elements and their values.

```
function flip2Front(tile, val) {
  tile.style.background = '#FFF';
  tile.innerHTML = val;
}

function surrender() {
  var tiles = document.querySelectorAll('div[id^="tile_"]');

  tiles.forEach(function(tile, i) {
    flip2Front(tile, memory_array[i]);
  });
}
```

### Working Demo

```js
var memory_array = ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'E', 'E', 'F', 'F', 'G', 'G', 'H', 'H', 'I', 'I', 'J', 'J', 'K', 'K', 'L', 'L'];
var memory_values = [];
var memory_tile_ids = [];
var tiles_flipped = 0;

Array.prototype.memory_tile_shuffle = function() {
  var i = this.length,
    j, temp;
  while (--i > 0) {
    j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    temp = this[j];
    this[j] = this[i];
    this[i] = temp;
  }
}

newBoard();

function newBoard() {
  tiles_flipped = 0;
  var output = '';
  memory_array.memory_tile_shuffle();
  for (var i = 0; i < memory_array.length; i++) {
    output += '<div id="tile_' + i + '" onclick="memoryFlipTile(this,\'' + memory_array[i] + '\')"></div>';
  }
  document.getElementById('memory_board').innerHTML = output;
}

function memoryFlipTile(tile, val) {
  if (tile.innerHTML == "" && memory_values.length < 2) {
    flip2Front(tile, val); // Reuse the function here.
    if (memory_values.length == 0) {
      memory_values.push(val);
      memory_tile_ids.push(tile.id);
    } else if (memory_values.length == 1) {
      memory_values.push(val);
      memory_tile_ids.push(tile.id);
      if (memory_values[0] == memory_values[1]) {
        tiles_flipped += 2;
        // Clear both arrays
        memory_values = [];
        memory_tile_ids = [];
        // Check to see if the whole board is cleared
        if (tiles_flipped == memory_array.length) {
          alert("Board cleared... generating new board");
          document.getElementById('memory_board').innerHTML = "";
          newBoard();
        }
      } else {
        setTimeout(flip2Back, 700);
      }
    }
  }
}

function flip2Front(tile, val) {
  tile.style.background = '#FFF';
  tile.innerHTML = val;
}

function flip2Back() {
  // Flip the 2 tiles back over
  var tile_1 = document.getElementById(memory_tile_ids[0]);
  var tile_2 = document.getElementById(memory_tile_ids[1]);
  tile_1.style.background = 'url(/game/images/catA.png) no-repeat';
  tile_1.innerHTML = "";
  tile_2.style.background = 'url(/game/images/cat.png) no-repeat';
  tile_2.innerHTML = "";
  // Clear both arrays
  memory_values = [];
  memory_tile_ids = [];
}

function surrender() {
  var tiles = document.querySelectorAll('div[id^="tile_"]');

  tiles.forEach(function(tile, i) {
    flip2Front(tile, memory_array[i]); // Reuse the function here.
  });
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  display: none !important;
}

div#memory_board {
  background: #CCC;
  border: #999 1px solid;
  width: 800px;
  height: 540px;
  padding: 24px;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

div#memory_board>div {
  background: url(/game/images/cat.png) no-repeat;
  border: #000 1px solid;
  width: 71px;
  height: 71px;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 64px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="memory_board"></div>
<input type="button" name="surrender" onclick="surrender();" value="Surrender!!">
<input type="button" name="restart" onclick="newBoard();" value="Restart!!">
```

Comment: Good suggestions, show the use of the data attribute.

Answer (score 0):

```
function surrender() {  
    var memoryBoard = document.getElementById("memory_board");
    var tiles = memoryBoard.childNodes;
    for (var i=0; i<tiles.length; i++) {
       var tile = tiles[i];
       var val  =tile.dataset.letter;
       tile.style.background = '#FFF';
       tile.innerHTML = val;
    }
}
```

For this to work edit yout tile output to (I added an attribute so that I can easily get the value):

`output += '<div id="tile_'+i+'"onclick="memoryFlipTile(this,\''+memory_array[i]+'\')" data-letter="'+memory_array[i]+'"></div>';`